# Good Link Tracking Plugin?

Tags: extensions, emails

I am looking for a good way to track links.

I would like to be able to add a small code after a link that I could give individually to people. So for example, www.website.com/how-to-swim/customer1 or some kind of link parameters. That way, I know which customers viewed the webpage and which ones did not. The feature of emailing me upon link visit would be very useful too.

I'm aware of Google Analytics UTM parameters, but as far as I can tell its goal is to track campaigns, not every customer.

Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. I have this excelent component installed. This can monitor all pages visited from your user after login.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/content-statistics

2. You can use Acy Mailyng component to send e-mails and track they access, if page was visited.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/acymailing-starter

I hope this helps.